# Should I use SQLite instead of MySQL?

Tags: mysql, performance, sqlite

I need to improve a PHP-MySQL web application, which only uses MySQL for REPL operations (and some search functions). 99% of the applications that I worked with never used advanced MySQL features, like replication, cross-table constraints, locking etc.

To my understanding I should instead use SQLite.

Are there any practical benefits if I do this?
Will I see a significant (>100ms) speed boost?
Should I expect problems with tables with more than 1,000,000 rows?

Comment: Do you encounter any problems when using MySQL?

Comment: @PeeHaa no. but I'm curious if there will be any benefits - performance - simplicity - that kind of stuff

Comment: It's from 2008, but: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630/sqlite-vs-mysql

Comment: They are two different databases designed for different scenarios .. Not Constructive. A quick google search should clear up doubts as to when one or the other or both might be most appropriate for a particular task/approach.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no catch-all answer to that, but there is a main point to consider: A very good rule of thumb is, that the higher your degree of concurrency is, the more you'll profit from MySQL and vice versa.

This means that in a scenario where database requests never ever are concurrent, you might see a speedup by using SQlite, though I doubt it would be in the 100ms order of magnitude.

The reason behind this is (very roughly):

In a database server environment, such as MySQL, PostgreSQL, MS SQL, Oracle and friends, a dedicated process (or a group of processes) exclusively touch the database files - the important part being **dedicated**. This means, that concurrency issues can be resolved in-process.

In a file-based database, such as SQlite, MS Access (Jet Engine) and friends, multiple processes will touch the DB files without knowing of each other - this implies that concurrency issues have to be resolved by writing them to the DB or helper file(s). This is typically much slower and less robust. In exchange for that, the overhead of communication between the database client (the web app) and the database server (which is in-process) is nonexistent.

**Edit**

After comment I want to make it more clear, that I am talking of concurrent writes, not concurrent reads. Concurrent reads of an unchanging dataset is not a hard problem - it doesn't need any locking at all.

Comment: Concurrency here is predominately "concurrent/mixed writes". SQLite basically has free "concurrent reads"; the file locking/contention occurs when locks must be obtained which differs slightly between WAL and traditional operational modes. Also, **SQLite is fully ACID-compliant and is just as "robust" as client-server databases** (barring a few very specific edge cases with lack of guaranteed fsync in very specific situations/non-local filesystems that are discussed elsewhere). However, the "cost" of this ACID is needing to obtain system-level file locks which is what limits write concurrency.

Comment: @pst Updated my answer to reflect more clearly I was talking about writes, not reads.

Comment: Concerning robustness my opinion is, that the tradeoff between failure resilientness and performance still favours the database server against the file-based database. Everybody having run into SQlite's infamous "database locked" after unclean shutdown requiring manual intervention will likely be of the same opinion, and I haven't yet started on other members of the file-based family. THis **definitly** is not to be understood as a critisism of SQlite: I consider SQlite as an exceptionally good member of this family and I use it quite regularily.

Comment: SQLite is ACID-compliant and **very** robust. The few edge-cases are documented on http://sqlite.org - barring a hardware or critical filesystem failure (which would be just as bad for MySQL, etc) there is no issue.

Comment: I hope to have made this clear enough now! Please understand, that english is not my first language.

Comment: I think it's a fair answer (I gave a +1, although I suspect this question will be closed). I am defending against "This is typically much slower and *less robust.*" :) The SQLite proponents (like me) strongly disagree on this point; is SQLite were *not* robust then it could not claim to be ACID.

Comment: Again: The "less robust" part is **not** a property of SQlite. It's a property of the family of databases, that SQlite belongs to, and while SQlite does an exceptionally good job of working around this, it can't fully cure this inherited weakness. It stems from the fact, that there is no "startup" procedure for a file-based database, which makes restart after an external failure more likely to need manual intervention, than a DB server would have. To make this absolutely clear: A DB server based on SQlite would not have this problem.

Comment: What do you mean by concurrency? Are you telling me that PHP will not do all operations in a single process, using (the same) persistent connection every time? Just asking...

Comment: If more than one request is handled by the webserver at the same time, it is **almost guaranteed**, that the database file will be concurrently used by **more than one** process. SQlite is made for that, this is the way it functions. My above comments still stand: The more concurrency, the better the case for a dedicated DB server, such as MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

The principal advantage of SQLite is that it is a file-based relational database that uses SQL as its query language. Being file-based tremendously simplifies deployment, making it very good for the case where an application needs a little database but must be run in an environment where having a database server would be problematic. (For example, many browsers use SQLite to manage their cookie stores; using a database server for that problem would be verging on the insane in many ways.)

The principal advantage of MySQL (with a sane table type) is that it is a database server that uses SQL as its query language. Being server-based allows for many features that a file-based system can't handle simply (such as replication) but does make things quite a bit more complex to deploy.

Whether the benefits of the additional complexity of a database server (e.g., MySQL) outweigh the costs (relative to a file-based database engine like SQLite) depends on a great many factors, notably including how many installations are expected and who is expected to perform those installations.